# Why Retry is not triggered when I use resilience4j functional configuration?

Tags: java, spring-boot, resilience4j, resilience4j-retry

I had successful experiments with spring boot configuration for resillence4j but I want to try functional configuration.

So I have implemented following code:

```
    RetryConfig config = RetryConfig.custom()
            .maxAttempts(6)
            .waitDuration(Duration.ofMillis(100))
            .build();

    RetryRegistry registry = RetryRegistry.of(config);

    Retry retry = registry.retry("name1");
    Retry.decorateCheckedSupplier(retry, myService::bar);

    myService.bar();
```

---

```
@Service
@Slf4j
public class MyService {
    public String bar() throws InterruptedException {
        log.error("Bar is called");
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        if (true) {
            throw new RuntimeException("bar exception");
        }
        return "Success";
    }
}
```

When I start the application I see **single** error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: bar exception
```

Why retry was not triggered ?

Comment: As per 1st snap code you are calling direct service due to this retry seems to be ignored, to execute can't we use get() function to execute retry like Retry.decorateCheckedSupplier(retry, myService::bar).get();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I had to use decorator instead of raw function.
Correct implemtation is:

```
CheckedFunction0<String> decoratedFunction = Retry.decorateCheckedSupplier(retry, myService::bar);
decoratedFunction.apply();
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you use Spring Boot, there is no need for manual configuring of `RetryConfig`, the `RetryRegistry`  registry, etc. All the configuration is handled by the framework as you define entries only in `application.yml`.

```yaml
resilience4j:
  retry:
    instances:
      retry-bar:              # custom backend instance name definition
        maxRetryAttempts: 5
        waitDuration: 100ms
```

If you don't do it and you want to stick with `RetryConfig` and other configuration classes, you have to define them all as `@Bean` in the `@Configuration` class and make sure they are component-scanned by Spring.

---

To apply the retry configuration, annotate the method `bar` with the `@Retry` annotation to suggest the method should be decorated with the retry mechanism:

```java
@Retry("retry-bar")
public String bar() throws InterruptedException {
    log.error("Bar is called");
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    if (true) {
        throw new RuntimeException("bar exception");
    }
    return "Success";
}
```

Reference:

- Resilience4j & Spring Boot integration: https://resilience4j.readme.io/docs/getting-started-3
- Refactoring article: https://reflectoring.io/retry-with-springboot-resilience4j

Comment: Based on information I've read functiona style is more flexible. What if I want to have cicuite breaker over retry for endpoint#1 and retry over cicuite breaker fpr endpoint#2 ? looks like spring boot config doesn't support it